# Reagent :component-did-mount

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, reagent

I'm trying to set the initial focus on an input element

```
(defn initial-focus-wrapper [element]
  (with-meta element
    {:component-did-mount #(.focus (reagent/dom-node %))}))

(defn chat-input []
  (fn []
    [initial-focus-wrapper
      [:input {:type "text"}]]))
```

This doesn't work for me though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but if you provide the `autoFocus` prop with the value `true`, that should work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As sbensu says `with-meta` only seems to work in reagent on a function. This means it can be used with `identity` to produce a reusable wrapper as hoped

```
(def initial-focus-wrapper 
  (with-meta identity
    {:component-did-mount #(.focus (reagent/dom-node %))}))

(defn chat-input []
  (fn []
    [initial-focus-wrapper
      [:input {:type "text"}]]))
```

Comment: For those struggling you need to use (reagent/as-element [chat-input]) to render it properly.

Answer (score 5):

I think `with-meta` should take a function as an argument. From the docs:

```clj
(def my-html (atom ""))

(defn plain-component []
  [:p "My html is " @my-html])

(def component-with-callback
  (with-meta plain-component
    {:component-did-mount
     (fn [this]
       (reset! my-html (.-innerHTML (reagent/dom-node this))))}))
```

So your code should be:

```clj
(defn initial-focus-wrapper [element]
  (with-meta element
    {:component-did-mount #(.focus (reagent/dom-node %))}))

(defn chat-input []
  [initial-focus-wrapper
    (fn []
      [:input {:type "text"}]]))
```

Comment: You're right. Reagent only seems to work when with-meta is applied to a function. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with an anonymous function either

Answer (score 1):

Another way to set the focus on a given component is to use the ":auto-focus true" attribute:

```clj
(defn chat-input []
  [:input {:type "text" :auto-focus true}]])
```